# Nao percebo porque não funciona

Tags: java

Pessoal tenho aqui um problema, não sei porque é que isto não imprime nada. Não tem erros de compilação, mas não funciona.

#### Classe Alunos

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Alunos {
    private String primeiro;
    private String segundo;
    private int idade;
    private static int quantidade;

    Alunos(String pn,String sn,int i){
        primeiro=pn;
        segundo=sn;
        idade=i;
        quantidade++;
        System.out.printf("Aluno %s %s juntou-se a turma, ele tem %d anos!A turma tem agora %d alunos. \n",primeiro , segundo, idade,quantidade);
    }

    
}
```

#### Classe Teste

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.EnumSet;

public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        String pn;
        String sn;
        int idade = 0;

        for (int contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++) {
            System.out.println("Insira o primeiro nome, segundo nome e idade:");
            pn = sc.nextLine();
            sn = sc.nextLine();
            idade = sc.nextInt();
            Alunos Aluno = new Alunos(pn, sn, idade);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Aqui no meu teste imprimiu normalmente, após pedir os parâmetros via teclado: "Aluno murillo goulart juntou-se a turma, ele tem 28 anos!A turma tem agora 1 alunos. "

Comment: sim mas se fizer outra vez vai dar um erro , se continuar o ciclo for

Comment: O motivo do erro e como solucionar está explicado nas respostas desta pergunta linkada.

Answer (score 4):

No código do seu for, faça a instanciação do `Scanner` novamente:

```
    for (int contador = 0; contador < 5; contador++) {
        System.out.println("Insira o primeiro nome, segundo nome e idade:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        pn = sc.nextLine();
        sn = sc.nextLine();
        idade = sc.nextInt();
        Alunos Aluno = new Alunos(pn, sn, idade);
    }
```

ps. Há outras práticas que não estão sendo seguidas, mas não vou prolongar a questão.

Answer (score 1):

É preciso atribuir um valor inicial para a variável "quantidade" na classe Alunos

```
private static int quantidade = 0;
```

Abraço

Comment: Esta variável é inicializada implicitamente. Então não é esse o problema.